# Allegro 4 , load gif image

Tags: bitmapimage, allegro

I am trying to create a program using allegro 4 to load a few images for creating a space invaders User interface.

```
#include <allegro.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *filename = "ship.gif";
    BITMAP *image;
    int ret;

allegro_init(); 
install_keyboard(); 
set_color_depth(16);

ret = set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 640, 480, 0, 0);
if (ret != 0) {
    allegro_message(allegro_error);
    return 1;
}

//load the image file
image = load_bitmap(filename, NULL);

if (!image) {
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_TEXT, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    allegro_message("Error loading %s", filename);
    return 1;
}

//display the image
blit(image, screen, 0, 0, 0, 0, SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H);

//done drawing--delete bitmap from memory
destroy_bitmap(image);
//display video mode information
textprintf_ex(screen,font,0,0,1,-1,"%dx%d",SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H);

while (!keypressed());

//exit program
allegro_exit();
return 0;
}

END_OF_MAIN()
```

This is my code and i am trying to load a few images to form a space invaders User interface..When i run it , it show 
error loading ship.gif..Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Allegro 4 doesn't support loading gif images. You'll need something like this:

http://algif.sourceforge.net/